# Revert Windows 7 boot animation to something like vista or xp

Tags: windows-7, boot

I know that people have the issue if the number of vertical pixels on their screen is less than 768, they will get a vista like boot animation. Is there a way to do this for a computer that normally plays the default boot animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. You have to set the bootmenu language to a language where you don't have a MUI pack installed. So if you use EN-US Windows, set the language to de-DE for example:

```
bcdedit /set {current} locale de-DE
```

Now Windows can't find the German files and reverts back to the old Vista progressbar bootlogo.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the locale?

Comment: This is the only way I know.